# How to compute this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

I am stuck in computing this series (i.e, finding a closed-form formula):

$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \frac{2r^{i+1}(1-r)^{k-i+1}p^{k-i}v^i s^k}{(1-r)p^{k-i}s^i + r v^i s^{k-i}},
$$
where $r$, $p$, $v$, $s$ are constants in the range of $(0,1)$. Any help/hint/comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't do the lines of calculus all the way but if you set $a_i:=(1-r)p^{k-i}s^i  \text{ and } b_i:=r v^i s^{k-i}$ then your sum will be $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} r^i(1-r)^{k-i}\frac{2a_ib_i}{a_i+b_i}$ maybe you could use something like $2a_ib_i=(a_i+b_i)^2-(a_i^2+b_i^2)$ then.